# Mesh with clean weight paint distorts unexpectedly

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting, pose-mode

i have a model i've been working on, that came with weight painting on it. i made a few edits, set the rig as the parent again, and for some reason when i move the left hand... this happens

[image]

when i move the left hand, the characters body shifts with it, but i had checked all the weight painting and it's only painted for the hand. it also seems exclusive to this hand, and automatic weights also distorts the model

i was hoping someone could help me with this problem please!

**[(.blend file)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iuta94GIQncxmI1RvGJtDBZ3CUeBrRdd/view?usp=sharing)**